# Compare two JSON files and select all entries with a changed attribute

Tags: json, unix, jq

I have two JSON files with peers statistics:

File1.json:

```
{
  "transferIN": 111111,
  "transferOUT": 111234,
  "IPs": [
    "10.1.1.1/32"
  ]
}
{
  "transferIN": 111222,
  "transferOUT": 222234,
  "IPs": [
    "10.1.1.2/32"
  ]
}
{
  "transferIN": 111333,
  "transferOUT": 333556,
  "IPs": [
    "10.1.1.3/32"
  ]
}
{
  "transferIN": 111444,
  "transferOUT": 444875,
  "IPs": [
    "10.1.1.4/32"
  ]
}
```

File2.json:

```
{
  "transferIN": 111111,
  "transferOUT": 111234,
  "IPs": [
    "10.1.1.1/32"
  ]
}
{
  "transferIN": 111345,
  "transferOUT": 222233,
  "IPs": [
    "10.1.1.2/32"
  ]
}
{
  "transferIN": 111333,
  "transferOUT": 333990,
  "IPs": [
    "10.1.1.3/32"
  ]
}
{
  "transferIN": 111446,
  "transferOUT": 4448456,
  "IPs": [
    "10.1.1.4/32"
  ]
}
```

I want to compare them and get a list of IPs only which has a changed "transferIN" key.

So output should be like this:
10.1.1.2/32
10.1.1.4/32

I will use this in the bash script. So I started to look into jq.

What I did:

```
jq -n --slurpfile file1 File1.json --slurpfile file2 File2.json '$file2 - $file1' | jq .[] | jq -r .IPs[]
```

But this only show peers that have any changed stats (transferOUT can change also)

10.1.1.2/32
10.1.1.3/32
10.1.1.4/32

Also looked to INDEX and map_values but with no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to compare items of matching positions within their respective streams, you could slurp just one file, and successively read in the other file's items as a stream using `input` while iterating over the slurped ones using `$file1[]`:

```bash
<File2.json jq --slurpfile file1 File1.json -rn \
  '$file1[] | select(.transferIN != input.transferIN).IPs[]'
```

```
10.1.1.2/32
10.1.1.4/32
```

Comment: thank you, exactly what I needed!
Sorry, I still can't cast an upvote for you (no repo), but I hope someone will found this and send you a rewarding reputation point :)